# Is there a way to highlight the (s) expression you are in?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting, smartparens

I currently have `(paren-set-mode 'paren)` in my `init.el`, and it does a good job of highlighting the area between parentheses. However, I was wondering if there was a way to highlight the expression I am inside of. So if I have this code `(fads fasd fasdf^ asdf asfds)`, with the `^` representing my cursor, could I highlight the expression automatically? Is there a way to do this so that it would also do the same for the `do/end` blocks like in Elixir and Ruby?

Comment: Which expression enclosing point? There are at least two in what you show, and in general there can be many. IOW, your request is underspecified.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options detailed on the Wiki:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSexp
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSexps

Comment: Thank you @phils! That's exactly what I was looking for.